# Can't get JDBC driver working with a local PostgreSQL 13 DB

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm using a PostgreSQL 13 database on a Windows 10 System, and I'm trying to connect to it using Java and the JDBC driver, but I keep getting errors and I have no clue what the problem might be.

This is my code:

```
static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/NIRONDB";
static String user = "postgres";
static String password = "#C3T\\<L[q^.G~QnSXrn";

Properties props = new Properties();



public static void enterEvent(int price,int maxAttendees,int hostID,int minAge,String 
title,String location,String userInfo, String date, String time){

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
         Statement st = con.createStatement();
        
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from user");


    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(DBHandler.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

    }

}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Der Authentifizierungstyp 10 wird nicht unterstützt. Stellen Sie 
    sicher, dass die Datei 'pg_hba.conf' die IP-Adresse oder das Subnetz des Clients enthält und dass 
    der Client ein Authentifizierungsschema nutzt, das vom Treiber unterstützt wird.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:504)
    at 
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't read german, but it seems that your PostgreSQL is not configured to accept connections on that port on `localhost`. Try connecting using `psql` with the same host and port, and if you get a similar error, you'll need to reconfigure your PostgreSQL.

Comment: You are using an outdated JDBC driver version

Comment: tried conneting to the db via psql and it worked no problem and used the latest stable driver for postgres recomennded by intellij

Comment: Which version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: version 42.2.5 stable

Comment: updated the version to 42.2.18 but that didnt change anything